# npm modules not found

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, debian

I have a debian 9 server with latest version of nodejs

I have a vuejs app when i want to build it npm run build, I have errors:

```
⠋  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                                           12:42:13 PM

This relative module was not found:

* ../config in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/login.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/signup.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 3 others
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! moveup-vuejs@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the moveup-vuejs@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-30T10_42_13_354Z-debug.log
```

This is the log it gives on error:

```
root@vps723374:/var/www/moveup-vuejs# cat /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-30T10_58_13_481Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle moveup-vuejs@0.1.0~prebuild: moveup-vuejs@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle moveup-vuejs@0.1.0~build: moveup-vuejs@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle moveup-vuejs@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle moveup-vuejs@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/moveup-vuejs/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
9 verbose lifecycle moveup-vuejs@0.1.0~build: CWD: /var/www/moveup-vuejs
10 silly lifecycle moveup-vuejs@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service build' ]
11 silly lifecycle moveup-vuejs@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle moveup-vuejs@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: moveup-vuejs@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid moveup-vuejs@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /var/www/moveup-vuejs
16 verbose Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error moveup-vuejs@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the moveup-vuejs@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I don' t know if it heps, when i do npm install i have warnings:

```
root@vps723374:/var/www/moveup-vuejs# npm install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

My vue.js

```
<template>
  <div>
  ....
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { ApiUrl } from "../config";
export default {
  name: "signup",
  data() {
    return {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      c_password: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    signup: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      axios
        .post(ApiUrl + "/signup", {
          firstname: this.firstname,
          lastname: this.lastname,
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
          c_password: this.c_password,
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data.success.token);
          this.$router.push("/login");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

What is strange is it build perfectly on another server.

I remove the nodejs install, reinstall it, try another version, ect without success, I m running out of idea, any idea where it' s coming from ?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the content of signup.vue ? 
I think it may be related to the relative path you are using ./src/components/signup.vue 
Try to put @/components/signup.vue (@ is a default alias for ./src/ in vuejs default config)

Comment: Might also be useful if you can post the log file: /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-30T10_42_13_354Z-debug.log

Comment: @DavidPi i don' t think it' s about the path, as the folders path are exactly on both servers, and it works fine on the preprod